# Share the dataset over Spark calculations

Tags: apache-spark

I have a huge data file (200Gb+) which contains of daily metrics (millions of metrics).

For each metric I'll have to calculate some value based on a predefined set of time periods (e.g. 10, 50, 100, 365 days).

1. The calculation happens daily, time periods are not changed, all periods are calculated each time.
2. results can be reused (from 10-series can be reused for 50 and so on, from 50 - for 100 and so on)
3. records in file are not sorted

I'm wondering if there are some Spark patterns which can be applied to read the file once, cache results for #2, etc.

Comment: you can compute the 10 day granularity first since the data isn't really sorted. Then you can persist that dataframe and compute all the other ones from that.

Comment: in this case I'll have to start reading from the beginning because the data is not sorted

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure about your implementation, but if you want to cache huge dataset and share it among Spark jobs, you can take a look at [Alluxio](https://www.alluxio.io/).

Simple implementation is read file, do some transportation and write to Alluxio, your 2nd spark job will read Alluxio directly to get data which are cached to memory by Alluxio.

[image: Alluxio Architecture with Spark and Other Computation Engines]